# Parsing sql strings

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a method as below:

```
public boolean ReadingMade(int id, String readingdate)
{

    String selectQuery = "Select * From " + TABLE_METERREADING + " Where " +TENANTMETER_ID+ "="  +id + " And " + READINGDATE +"=" + readingdate;
    Log.e("LOG", selectQuery);      
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        c.close();
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
        c.close();
        return false;
    }

}
```

I want to pass the string argument using a value from edit-text e.g

```
EditText readDate= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
if (db.ReadingMade(id,readDate.getText().toString()) ==true)
        {
```

I get a string like one below

```
Select * From MeterReading Where TenantMeter_id=1 And ReadingDate=2014-01-20
```

Yet sq-lite expects

```
Select * From MeterReading Where TenantMeter_id=1 And ReadingDate='2014-01-20'
```

How do i pull it off?

Comment: Dear user, all the answers below are correct, you can mark any of these answers as accepted (ofcourse, if it helped you)...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
    String selectQuery = "Select * From " + TABLE_METERREADING + " Where " +TENANTMETER_ID+ "="  +id + " And " + READINGDATE +"=" + readingdate;
```

to

```
    String selectQuery = "Select * From " + TABLE_METERREADING + " Where " +TENANTMETER_ID+ "="  +id + " And " + READINGDATE +"= '" + readingdate+"'";
```

Comment: Click on the tick mark that you can see beside my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I have not misunderstood you, that should work

```
"='" + readingdate + "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` placeholders for literals to prevent the need to escape special characters in literals and to avoid SQL injection attacks:

```
String selectQuery = "Select * From " + TABLE_METERREADING + " Where " +TENANTMETER_ID+ "=? And " + READINGDATE +"=?";
// ...
String[] args = new String[] { Integer.toString(id), readingdate };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, args);
```

(There's a performance benefit to `?` args as well but it's normally not visible in the way Android SQLite API is used.)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Other answers leave you open to injection attacks and miss the utility of the ? parameter replacement feature in db.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to change.